# Can`t install datasets in R, not cvs and not xlsx

Tags: r

I am new to RStudio. And it was working well, about a week ago my computer update the new version of the system. And from this moment R doesnt work like before. I am trying to load at datasets in .xlsx and .cvs - it doesn`t work. *R write like this:*

```
** Installing R Package Dependencies for Excel Import: `'readxl', 'Rcpp'`



[1/5] Installing cellranger...

�������������� � utils::install.packages("cellranger", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library"' is not writable
������ � utils::install.packages("cellranger", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  unable to install packages
������: sourceWithProgress -> eval -> eval -> <Anonymous>
���������� �����������
```

*I trying to install xlsx packages, it writes like this:*

```
`install.packages("xlsx")`
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Warning in install.packages :
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library"' is not writable
Warning in install.packages :
  не могу создать каталог 'C:\Users\Lina\OneDrive\?????????' по причине 'Invalid argument'
Error in install.packages : unable to create ‘C:/Users/Lina/OneDrive/?????????/R/win-library/4.0’
```

if somebody can help me?

Comment: The warning gives you the solution `WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/`

Comment: Additionally you seem to have no permissions to write to your library path. Make sure you have rights to write in `C:\Program Files\...' .And you seem to have problems with character format of your folder structures. Are you using kyrillic folder names?

Comment: First of all, `CSV` files not `cvs`. Secondly, I recommend not using `xlsx` package that relates to issues with Java, use `openxlsx` instead.

Comment: @Julian_Hn some folders yes on Cyrillic but files that I used in R on English. It was working, I haven`t problems like this before. I install Rtools it`s still don`t work.

Comment: @xwhitelight yes, of course, CSV, sorry. I am trying your version to use openxlsx, it does not work.

Comment: As I said, you don't seem to have writing permissions to your library folder. Can you install any packages at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you appear to be a Windows user, I can offer two pieces of advice.

First, make sure your R installation is in a location that you have write permissions to. In some Windows OS, the Program Files locations are by default locked down. If the computer is yours, you should be able to change the permissions to the R folder. How to do so will vary a little by your windows version, so I will not provide more instructions. One other thing you can try is to set R and RStudio to "Run as administrator".

Second, OneDrive is a bad place to put your R installation or your R packages. OneDrive does not support all filenames and file extensions. R and its packages will generate a number of unsupported files, and you will continually be notified that something will not sync and that you should do something about it.

On a Windows machine, I generally install R and set up the library at `C:\R` where I have appropriate permissions.

Comment: @LinaKanyavskaya - I'm glad. If the answer is helpful, consider voting on it. If it solved your problem, consider accepting it. You can also wait and see if a better answer comes along. See [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.